# Can I use server side payment integration in mobile using API's

Tags: php, laravel, api, stripe-payments

I am using the stripe for payment. I need a suggestion, Is it safe to send card detail through API to the server then make payment using stripe. Or I should create a token from mobile with stripe integration then send the token to the server for more processing.

Comment: Sending the actual card details means you have to be PCI compliant, which means $$$. Avoid at all costs by tokenizing using Stripe's JS libraries.

Comment: Completely agree with @ceejayoz - you would need to be PCI DSS compliant which costs a lot of money. I don't have any specific knowledge with Stripe but if they provide an option to tokenize the payment information then you should use this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you send the card information to your server it becomes your responsability to keep that data safe. Some payment gateways can request you some security audits before them allow you to use the gateway sending card data from server instead from browser.

I would recommend you keep using Stripe without sending credit card data to your server. If you get hacked you have a serious problem.

Answer (score 4):

As I think the best way the recommend to you keep information in  Stripe without sending credit card data to the server side.

I suggest you deal with the token(JWT/Passport)

There are some rules in the Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard. please follow this. This was very useful for me too :)

https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/faq/

Answer (score -6):

Yes.

You pass the card information from your mobile device to the server via API. The server will contact the payment service, get the result and return the result in the API return.